# From what regios does Vercel serve Next.js SSR responses?

Tags: next.js, vercel

When you deploy your Next.js app via the Vercel platform, in what region is the server placed?
I understand that for static content they use a CDN, but what about the good ol' SSR?
In my use case, I have an API server that is located on a Google Cloud VM in a specific region and I want to minimize the roundtrip between a Next.js server and the API.

Thank you and sorry if I missed it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "regions" configuration: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/regions

Comment: that's a bit I don't fully understand: is your Next.js server considered a serverless function?

Comment: A Serverless Function will render one or more pages of your Next.js app. It is not accurate to say the "next.js server" is considered a serverless function even if they both can produce the same result.